# How do I draw a sprite on top of a video in Andengine?

Tags: andengine, draw-order

I'm playing a video in Andengine on

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {}
```

However, when I place a sprite on the screen at some point in time, it is placed behind that video view. I want it to appear in front of it.

My attempt:

```
Entity foregroundLayer= new Entity();
foregroundLayer.attachChild(drag1);
scene.attachChild(foregroundLayer);
```

Setting `setZIndex` also didn't work

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The world icon is half outside and half behind. It should be on top.

Comment: NB: you may want to switch to libGDX. It's comparable, and AndEngine is not really maintained any more.

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward, I think:

- Set Z index of your `WorldIcon` higher than `VideoView`.
- Do `scene.sortChildren()` to apply the Z index sorting.

Comment: videoView is attached to layout and world icon is sprite attached to sceen

Comment: OK . so your using layoutgameActivity? try to set contentView of video layout before attaching the sprite to scene

Answer (score -1):

try [this](http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.com/2015/04/how-to-put-sprite-on-top-in-andengine.html). In short terms you have to rearrange the rendering order.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Links will degrade and become corrupt. It's always best to include relevant parts of the link in the answer.